# TCP Termination

Tags: http, tcp, communication

What is happening to a TCP connection after
an end of an HTTP session?
for example, after loading a static webpage from a webserver

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP session usually refers to the server is keeping an association to a specific user and could potentially be of any length (using, for instance, cookies as association tokens).

A HTTP session therefore usually contains multiple TCP sessions. For non persistent HTTP connections, every request has its own TCP session (and is closed after). For persistent HTTP connections on the other hand, multiple HTTP resources could be fetched wihtin a TCP session and either side will close it upon a reached timeout threshold on either side.

[Wikipedia article on Persistent HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) (Keep-Alive: true)

Answer (score 0):

You can have several HTTP request in one TCP connection. So it if you refer a HTTP session as a set of HTTP requests/responses, the TCP connection will be closed.

At TCP level the closing side sends a packet with the FIN flag set, the other side acknowledges this with ACK, and immediately or eventually does his own FIN, which the first acknowledges again with ACK. It's also possible that the connection is abandonded with the RST instead of FIN flag. The port that sent the first FIN goes into the TIME_WAIT state. This is used to reject packets that arrive subsequently, that would otherwise be misinterpreted as packets of a new connection. After the timeout the port goes from the TIME_WAIT state to the CLOSED state.

Edit: Normal termination is indicated by the FIN flag.

Comment: so in conclusion, after the http session is over
the tcp seesion is over too..
right?

Comment: You seem to be implying that RST as the only way to close a connection.  FIN, FIN-ACK, ACK are missing from your answer.  Those in fact are a more common close sequence than RST.

Comment: There are several errors in the above. It is not certain that the peer will respond with a FIN+ACK. He may just respond with an ACK if he doesn't close the connection immediately on receipt of the FIN. Only the peer that sent the first FIN goes into the TIME_WAIT state: a peer that receives a FIN before it has sent one does not. You have mis-stated the purpose of TIME_WAIT: it is a security measure to prevent packet receipt from new connections being mistakenly referred to the old connection. After the timeout the *port* goes from the TIME_WAIT state to the CLOSED state.